# Error al adjuntar fichero con NodeMailer

Tags: nodejs, nodemailer

Estoy usando Nodemailer e intentado adjuntar un archivo PDF que está en un servidor local "file:\172.10.x.xx\Carpeta\NOMBREARCHIVO.pdf". Mi configuración de NodeMailer se ve así:

```
var mailOptions = {
  from: "correo1@correo.com",
  to:"correo2@gmail.com",
 // to: mail,
  subject: "Enviado desde nodemailer",
  text: "namespdf",
  attachment: [{
    filename: 'NOMBREPDF.pdf',
    path: 'file:\\172.11.2.91\nombraCarpeta\NOMBREPDF.pdf',
    contentType: 'application/pdf',

  }]
```

Pero cuando ejecuto, recibo el siguiente mensaje de error:

```
C:\Users\JAFERRUCHO\Documents\conexion_oracle>node index.js
Server is running on http://localhost:8000
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\JAFERRUCHO\Documents\conexion_oracle\file:\172.11.1.90PrintQueueR03B11Z1A_KZJDE0002_183842_PDF.pdf'] {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ESTREAM',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\JAFERRUCHO\\Documents\\conexion_oracle\\file:\\172.11.1.90PrintQueueR03B11Z1A_KZJDE0002_183842_PDF.pdf',
  command: 'API'
}
```

¿Cómo puedo acceder al archivo pdf y adjuntarlo correctamente al envío del correo?

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. El código en tu pregunta debe ir en formato texto, y no en imagen. Saludos

Comment: Estás en Windows, pero los paths (p.e. `path: 'file:\\172.11.2.91\nombraCarpeta\NOMBREPDF.pdf',`) deberían ser con / en vez de \. Y si necesitas que sea \, deberás escapar el carácter y poner dos: \\.